# How to disable a function on resize / orientationchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have this function call `APP.utilities.anchor.scrollTo($(element).find('a'));` which scrolls to an element after an event named `afterChange`. I am using slick carousel and I would like to disable the `scrollTo` function on resize / orientationchange or the `afterChange` event.

This is what I have

```
var reInitSlickOnResize = function () {
    $slickCarousel.slick('resize');
};

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', reInitSlickOnResize);
```

And I have this function where I am calling the scrollTo function:

```
var handleIsActiveClass = function() {
    $slickCarousel.on('afterChange', function (slick, currentSlide) {
        var currenSlideIndex = currentSlide.currentSlide;
        $tabs.each(function (producTabIndex, element) {
            if (currenSlideIndex === producTabIndex) {                    
                // trigger scroll to focus on proper element
                APP.utilities.anchor.scrollTo($(element).find('a')); 
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The problem is that when resize / orientationchange happen, it automatically triggers 'afterChange' event, so I would like to know how to disable 'afterChange' event on `resize` or `orientationchange` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `afterChange` handler referenceable by using a named function, then you can detach the `afterChange` event before calling `.slick('resize')` and re-attach afterward.

```
function handleSlideChange(slick, currentSlide) {
  // ...
}

function handleIsActiveClass() {
  // Named function instead of anonymous function
  $slickCarousel.on('afterChange', handleSlideChange);
}

function reInitSlickOnResize() {
  $slickCarousel
    .off('afterChange', handleSlideChange)
    .slick('resize')
    .on('afterChange', handleSlideChange);
}

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', reInitSlickOnResize);
```

Another approach would be to use a flag to suppress behaviors:

```
var isResizing = false;

function handleIsActiveClass() {
  $slickCarousel.on('afterChange', function (slick, currentSlide) {
    if (isResizing) {
      return;
    }

    // ...
  });
}

function reInitSlickOnResize() {
  isResizing = true;
  $slickCarousel.slick('resize');
  isResizing = false;
}
```